# Which scripts run after each suspend or login, but not after a restart?

Tags: scripts, suspend, power-management

In the past I made a script that checked whether my battery was in my laptop. If so, it would a) cut the network connection, b) set the performance mode to powersave, and c) dim the screen. It has been a while and I don't remember how I did this, but now every time the computer suspends, abc take place.

Where could I have put this script/command?

Comment: I guess that depends on how long ago this was setup, ie which Ubuntu version. Also where you "put" the script may not be as important as where you are calling it "from".

Comment: Added it on 12.04, then the upgrade to 14.04 was fine, the update to 16.04 started causing issues (I know I know about the fresh install and the whole thing)

Comment: Probably something to do with how `systemd` does things differently but more digging is needed.

Comment: Any suggestions @WinEunuuchs2Unix on how to debug this?